# Ipyleaflet problems using python (don´t shows any map)

Tags: python, maps

I´m trying to use the ipyleaflet library on Google Datalab, and I was following this steps:

First, installing the libraries on both Python versions (2.7 and 3.6):

```
> %%bash
> 
> pip install ipyleaflet pip install ipywidgets jupyter nbextension
> enable --py --sys-prefix ipyleaflet jupyter nbextension enable --py
> widgetsnbextension
```

Results:

> Enabling notebook extension jupyter-leaflet/extension...
>         - Validating: OK Enabling notebook extension jupyter-js-widgets/extension...
>         - Validating: OK

Second, I was testing with this script, but nothing happens:

```
> from ipyleaflet import Map Map(center=[34.6252978589571,
> -77.34580993652344], zoom=10)
```

We don´t see any graph or map. Are we making somthing wrong?

Comment: Same Issue - Trying to fix it now!

Comment: I have same problem. Were you able to solve the problem?